# casting LEFT() from string to integer

Tags: postgresql

I have a date range column e.g. 1960-1970 in a table, I'm splitting these and copying them to new columns, I need to cast the string to an integer, the following code returns a generic syntax error, any ideas where I'm going wrong?

```
INSERT INTO rhp_tvp.time (
  visit_id_tmp, 
  tvp_id_tmp, 
  time_start, 
  time_end)

SELECT 
  v.visit_id, 
  v.tvp_id, 
  cast(LEFT(date_range, 4)AS int8), 
  cast(RIGHT(date_range, 4) AS int8)
FROM tvp.visit v 
WHERE  date_format = 'DMY' AND date_range NOT LIKE 'Pre%' OR date_range IS NOT NULL;
```

ERROR:  invalid input syntax for integer: "13/1"
SQL state: 22P02

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question and add the **exact** error message

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want something like this:

```
SELECT 
  v.visit_id, 
  v.tvp_id, 
  LEFT(date_range, 4)::INT, 
  RIGHT(date_range, 4)::INT
FROM tvp.visit v 
WHERE  date_format = 'DMY' AND date_range NOT LIKE 'Pre%';
```

To answer your question I did the following:

Created a table:

```
CREATE TABLE my_range(the_range VARCHAR(9)); -- just the field of interest!
```

Some sample values:

```
INSERT INTO my_range VALUES ('1969-1986');
INSERT INTO my_range VALUES ('1932-1987');
INSERT INTO my_range VALUES ('1956-1999');
```

Query:

```
SELECT LEFT(the_range, 4)::INT, RIGHT(the_range, 4)::INT FROM my_range;
```

Result:

```
Left Right
1969 1986
1932 1987
1956 1999
```

See the dbfiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=49c1bcbf76069879b1c8bf9bfb74e310).

You can check that they are now integers by running:

```
SELECT LEFT(the_range, 4)::INT + 20, RIGHT(the_range, 4)::INT - 20 FROM my_range;
```

And you can see that addition and subtraction are indeed performed on the new values in the fiddle.

Comment: cast AS or :: should not make the difference

Comment: There was a data error, fixing the data makes this work

Comment: Hmm... yes, puzzling - but the error `ERROR: invalid input syntax for integer: "13/1" SQL state: 22P02` suggests perhaps that there's a date in the format '13/1/XXXX' in there somewhere? Not really sure why. I do think that my answer is more "PostgreSQL-esqe" (c.f. [Pythonesque](http://www.yourdictionary.com/pythonesque)).